# How to handle fragment in fragment with Navigation Component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components

I would like to place a fragment inside a fragment and control it with Android X Navigation Component.
I want a login, register, setup wizard fragment and a Navigation Drawer fragment with some menus like: Home, Settings fragment etc. I would like to achieve something like this:

- MainNavigationHost

  - Login Fragment
  - Register Fragment
  - SetupWizard Fragment
  - Navigation Drawer Fragment (contains NavHost)

    - Home Fragment
    - Settings Fragment

I tried something like this. Two Navigation host. It works kindy but the backstack and the hamburger is not good. The navigation which happens in the Nav Drawer is not handled.

1. How can i achieve this?
2. Is navigation component should handle this kind of nesting?
3. Or i shouldn't use 2 NavHost? But then how i "inject" the fragments inside the nav drawer?

Comment: Anyone any idea?

Comment: Navigation represents top-level destinations. There is no reason for the NavigationDrawer to be a fragment at all.

Comment: Then it should be there all the time? For example if i display login then just display as content of the NavigationDrawer and disable open?

Comment: Yup, that's what people commonly do.

Comment: Thank you. That feels a little wierd but then i do this way.